Xpath - select all columns but the last
I am building a web scraper with Python and Selenium that scrapes the basketball reference website, and am in need of some fine-tuning of the Xpath statements that return the data I'm looking for. Currently, I need some Xpath statement that returns every column but the final one, which is the "awards" column, which sometimes contains text (if a player won any sort of award that year) or is blank if they did not. My code works fine and mostly does select what I need, but every variation of the Xpath statement I've tried either does not return a valid Xpath statement or it simply gives me the all the data including the last column, which I do not need. Here is a snippet of my working code along with the selenium driver code which retrieves every element of a table and returns it.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import pandas as pd

class PlayerPerGameStats():
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name.lower()
        self.options = Options()

        #No popup window when called
        self.options.add_argument("--headless=new")

        #No image loading for performance
        self.options.add_experimental_option(
            "prefs", {
                "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" : 2,
            }
        )
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        self.url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{self.player_name[0]}/{self.player_name}01.html"
        self.browser.get(self.url)

        #Add wait for page load
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'per_game_stats'))
        )

def get_player_row_stats(self) -> list:
        try:
            table = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'per_game_stats')
            rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, './tbody')
            stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './tr')]

            #List split to get each stat as it's own index
            player_data = [y for x in stat_rows for y in x.split(' ')]

            print(player_data)

            return player_data

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error extracting row stats: {e}")
            return None


#To run it
stats = PlayerPerGameStats("lillada")
player_stats = stats.get_player_row_stats()

And here the snippet of the DOM I am working with.
Snippet of basketball reference DOM
Some xpath variations I have tried include:
stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './tr[position() < last()]')]

stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './tr[not(contains(@data-stat, 'awards'))]')]

However these are not sufficient, and instead return every aforementioned column or just nothing at all.
Thank you for taking the time to read this. If any additional information or code is required I am more than happy to provide - this problem has been on my back for weeks now and I just want to figure out how to solve it.

This code doesn't run as you've posted it. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Also, when you say row... I think you mean column. The last column is the Awards column.

By the look of the table, the awards is a column, not a row. Do you need all the columns but the last one for all rows?

I do mean the last column, my apologies. I will reformat my question to better suite the stated requirements.

I changed your locators and approach. It excludes the last column in each row.
Working code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

player_name = "lillada"
url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{player_name[0]}/{player_name}01.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for row in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#per_game_stats tbody tr"))):
    player_data = [cell.text for cell in row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "th,td")[:-1]]
    print(player_data)

Output
['2012-13', '22', 'POR', 'NBA', 'PG', '82', '82', '38.6', '6.7', '15.7', '.429', '2.3', '6.1', '.368', '4.5', '9.6', '.469', '.501', '3.3', '3.9', '.844', '0.5', '2.6', '3.1', '6.5', '0.9', '0.2', '3.0', '2.1', '19.0']
['2013-14', '23', 'POR', 'NBA', 'PG', '82', '82', '35.8', '6.7', '15.9', '.424', '2.7', '6.8', '.394', '4.1', '9.1', '.447', '.508', '4.5', '5.2', '.871', '0.4', '3.1', '3.5', '5.6', '0.8', '0.3', '2.4', '2.4', '20.7']
['2014-15', ...


Thank you, this is exactly what I need. Is an Xpath statement alone not sufficient to get the same result? Or is CSS selector just a better way to handle scraping tasks?

You could convert the CSS selector to an XPath but CSS selectors are faster, better supported, and simpler syntax. I only use XPath when I need to get an element by contained text or do complex DOM traversal.

If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Can I suggest not using Selenium here. A bit over kill when the data is in the source html. Just get the html, and let pandas parse the table (it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood). Some of the tables are in the htnl comments, so you'll need to remove those (which we did in this code) for some tables.
The second part though that needed to be fixed was you never actually called your get_player_row_stats() function.
Code:
import requests
import pandas as pd

class PlayerPerGameStats():
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name.lower()

        self.url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{self.player_name[0]}/{self.player_name}01.html"

        response = requests.get(self.url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            self.html = response.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')  # Remove commented-out HTML
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch data. HTTP Status Code: {response.status_code}")



    def get_player_row_stats(self) ->  pd.DataFrame:
            try:
                player_data = pd.read_html(self.html, attrs={'id':'per_game_stats'})[0]
                print(player_data)
                return player_data
    
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error extracting row stats: {e}")
                return None


#To run it
stats = PlayerPerGameStats("lillada")
player_stats = stats.get_player_row_stats()

Output:
         Season           Age          Team  ...   PF   PTS           Awards
0        2012-13            22           POR  ...  2.1  19.0            ROY-1
1        2013-14            23           POR  ...  2.4  20.7          AS,NBA3
2        2014-15            24           POR  ...  2.0  21.0               AS
3        2015-16            25           POR  ...  2.2  25.1       MVP-8,NBA2
4        2016-17            26           POR  ...  2.0  27.0              NaN
5        2017-18            27           POR  ...  1.6  26.9    MVP-4,AS,NBA1
6        2018-19            28           POR  ...  1.9  25.8    MVP-6,AS,NBA2
7        2019-20            29           POR  ...  1.7  30.0    MVP-8,AS,NBA2
8        2020-21            30           POR  ...  1.5  28.8    MVP-7,AS,NBA2
9        2021-22            31           POR  ...  1.3  24.0              NaN
10       2022-23            32           POR  ...  1.9  32.2  CPOY-10,AS,NBA3
11       2023-24            33           MIL  ...  1.8  24.3       CPOY-11,AS
12       2024-25            34           MIL  ...  1.8  25.9              NaN
13        13 Yrs        13 Yrs        13 Yrs  ...  1.9  25.1              NaN
14           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...  NaN   NaN              NaN
15  POR (11 Yrs)  POR (11 Yrs)  POR (11 Yrs)  ...  1.9  25.2              NaN
16   MIL (2 Yrs)   MIL (2 Yrs)   MIL (2 Yrs)  ...  1.8  24.6              NaN

[17 rows x 31 columns]


the easiest solution is simply
stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './tr')][:-1]

i don't know with xpath, but with css selectors you can do
stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr td:not(:last-of-type)')]

